# Want to display information on the same position on page according to the User selection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have one asp.net page. On the left side there multiple buttons.
button1 for Merchant
button2 for Costumer 
button3 for Dealer 
ans so on .

So once  I click the button, Personal details  for that specified person will shown on the right side of same page (I am managing this by using panel control)and remember all person's forms are different. So number of panel control is equal to As many buttons I have.
.So If I select button1 for merchant details for merchant will be shown in its panel and If I select button2 for costumer details, his details will we shown.My problem is I want to show details Data at same position of the Page on the left side?
So Is there any other feasible way instead of using Panel Control??
Or If its could be done by Panel control itself please give me idea , how I should do.
Or If there is another way , the same functionality could be achieved, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: It is hard to visualize what you are trying to do, can you provide some code to show what you have built so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdatePanel is awesome for quick/small work AJAX, but when things get bigger the best way is to do AJAX manually.

You could make the right-side panels onto separated *.aspx files. It'll get better organized than multiple panels in the same page, also will be easier to work with each panel trait.

The best way to you do this is with Jquery Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/